# Auto-increment conflicting slugs on save

Tags: python, django

I need blog post slugs to be unique on a per user basis. When a user saves a new post in my Django project, I'd like it to check if the slug exists, and if it does, add a -1 to the end of it.

What's the best way to do this? I've added my code below, which is always adding the -1, and I'm sure there's a better way to do this

```
class Post(models.Model):
  ...

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=self.user, slug=self.slug)
    if self not in posts:
      self.slug = self.slug + '-1'
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What happens when there's a second (or third …) duplicate?

Comment: Currently it goes -1-1, -1-1-1.. also not ideal

Answer (score 0):

I found [this snippet](https://fazle.me/auto-generating-unique-slug-django-generic-approach/) very useful.

The main difference to yours is that it uses a `while` statement to check whether /blog-title-1/ exists, and if not it tries /blog-title-2/ etc until it finds an available slug.